# SVN & Visual Studio workflow

Tags: visual-studio-2008, svn, visualsvn

I downloaded and installed VisualSVN Server, VisualSVN and TortioseSVN.

The installation went well. I set the repository root as E:\Repositories. Once installed, I created a repository called Test, and added users. All is well so far.

I already had a test project created in Visual Studio 2008, located at D:\projects\test so I opened the project in Visual Studio and selected the VisualSVN -> Add Solution to SVN Menu item.

Where it says "the content of this folder will be added to subversion:" I left it as
d:\projects\test and clicked next. I chose existing repository, and typed in the URL for the repository I created after install (https:/mycomputer:443/svn/test/trunk).

It then said "Folder 'd:\projects\test' will be bound to 'https:/mycomputer:443/svn/test/trunk'."  Then I clicked finished. But I'm thinking that now 'd:\projects\test' is the repository source, when really it is my working location. What should I have done differently?

Comment: Sounds fine, from what I can tell.

Comment: @JW so where is SVN storing all the files now?  is it in e:\Repositories\Test or is it in d:\projects\test?  I don't think it should be d:\projects test, because that is my working directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A working copy has a **.svn** directory on every folder plus all your original files.

A repository has a **README.txt** file where it states "This is a Subversion repository" plus a format file and several directories (**conf**, **dav**, **db**, **hooks** and **locks**) but no visible trace of your original files.